# Yet another centering div alignment issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, html

I'm new to using CSS and have experience with old HTML, last time I designed a site was in 2002.
So i've been designing a new personal website for the past few days without a problem until i tried viewing my site in Internet Explorer (8 & 9).
After 2 whole days of searching for answers i've decided to ask for help. The site was looking as intended in Firefox and Chrome and i've just been tearing my hair out over it. The only thing i know for certain is adding the !doctype breaks it in both ie9 and ff.
I would love to have someone more experienced take a look at my code.
Hope to read a response soon.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<HEAD>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<!-- Nivo Slider Theme loading -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/sarrus/sarrus.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<TITLE>Sarrus Design Works</TITLE>
<!-- Layout CSS Link -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />

</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header" class="gradient">
      <img style="border:solid 2px #202020;" src="img/sdw-logo.jpg">
  </div>
        <!-- Nivo Slider Body attachment -->
<div id="content">
  <div class="slider-wrapper theme-sarrus">
        <!-- Add div class="ribbon" if theme contains ribbon -->
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="img/slider1.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="img/slider2.jpg" alt=""title="#htmlcaption" />
    <img src="img/slider3.jpg" alt=""title="This is an example of a caption" />
    <img src="img/slider4.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
<strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
</div>
  <div id="content2">
  </div>
<div id="details">
    All artwork is copyright of Mike Williams. Fanart original characters are copyright belonging to their respective owner.
</div>
</div>
</BODY>

 <!-- place scripts here -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
     effect:'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
     animSpeed:1000, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime:6000, // How long each slide will show
    startSlide:0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav:true, // Next & Prev navigation
    directionNavHide:true, // Only show on hover
    controlNav:true, // 1,2,3... navigation
    controlNavThumbs:false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    controlNavThumbsFromRel:false, // Use image rel for thumbs
    controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', // Replace this with...
    controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', // ...this in thumb Image src
    keyboardNav:true, // Use left & right arrows
    pauseOnHover:false, // Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance:false, // Force manual transitions
    captionOpacity:0.7, // Universal caption opacity
    prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
    nextText: 'Next' // Next directionNav text
 });
});
</script>
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
 .gradient {
   filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
</HTML>
```

and CSS

```
html {
height: 100%;
font-family:arial;
}

body {
text-align: center;
marginleft: ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding:0;
background: #ffffff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(136,110,191,0.76) 2%, rgba(136,110,191,0) 54%, rgba(136,110,191,0) 67%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(2%,rgba(136,110,191,0.76)), color-stop(54%,rgba(136,110,191,0)), color-stop(67%,rgba(136,110,191,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(136,110,191,0.76) 2%,rgba(136,110,191,0) 54%,rgba(136,110,191,0) 67%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(136,110,191,0.76) 2%,rgba(136,110,191,0) 54%,rgba(136,110,191,0) 67%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(136,110,191,0.76) 2%,rgba(136,110,191,0) 54%,rgba(136,110,191,0) 67%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(136,110,191,0.76) 2%,rgba(136,110,191,0) 54%,rgba(136,110,191,0) 67%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c2886ebf', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 );

 }

* {margin:0; padding:0;}

/* ----- Nivo Slider Settings ---- */
.nivoSlider {
   background:url(img/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.nivoSlider img {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
.nivoSlider a {
  border:0;
  display:block;

}

/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:5;
height:100%;
}
.nivo-box {
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:5;
}
/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
position:absolute;
text-align:left;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
background:#000;
color:#fff;
opacity:0.8; /* Overridden by captionOpacity setting */
width:100%;
z-index:8;
}
.nivo-caption p {
padding:5px;
margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
display:none;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
position:absolute;
top:45%;
z-index:9;
cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
right:0px;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav a {
position:relative;
z-index:9;
}

.nivo-controlNav a.active {
font-weight:bold;
}

#Wrapper {
text-align:left;
width: 850px; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}
#header {
position:relative;
z-index:50;
width:120px;
height:170px;
margin-left:30px;
border:solid 1px #404040;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0px #404040;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0px #404040;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0px #404040; 
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
background: rgb(125,126,125);
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%, rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(125,126,125,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(14,14,14,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 );

}

#slider  {
margin: 0 auto;
width:846;
height:433;
}

#content {
border:1px solid #b4b4b4;
padding:5px;
z-index:1;
width:100%;
margin-top:-85px;
background-color:#e9e9e9;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0px #404040;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0px #404040;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0px #404040; 
}

#content2 {
border:1px solid #b4b4b4;
padding:5px;
z-index:1;
width:100%;
height:200px;
background-color:#E9E9E9;
margin-top:10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0px #404040;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0px #404040;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 0px #404040;
}

#details {
padding:6px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
font-color:#b4b4b4;
font-filter:soft;
font-size:8px;
}
```

Sorry about the big post ^^ not sure what information you would need.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the layout? I've tried opening your website and it looks the same to me on IE9, Firefox, and Chrome. IE8 looks similar, but without the shadows along the edges. Could you provide any more details?

A link to your site might also be helpful because you use relative references that we cannot access.

Comment: My apologies, i've taken 2 screenshots;
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/website1.jpg/ - what it's supposed to look like.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/85/website2n.jpg/ - What it ends up looking like when i add the !doctype and when i open it in ie9 with or without the !doctype.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the `.nivo-caption` is getting its width based on body, because none of its parents have `position: relative`.
Are you able to set `position: relative` to the `.nivo-slider` element?